# How to filter a spark dataframe based on occurrence of a value in a column with a condition a date column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

team, I'm working with a dataframe looks like:

```
    df
    client   | date   
      C1     |08-NOV-18 11.29.43
      C2     |09-NOV-18 13.29.43
      C2     |09-NOV-18 18.29.43
      C3     |11-NOV-18 19.29.43
      C1     |12-NOV-18 10.29.43
      C2     |13-NOV-18 09.29.43
      C4     |14-NOV-18 20.29.43
      C1     |15-NOV-18 11.29.43
      C5     |16-NOV-18 15.29.43
      C10    |17-NOV-18 19.29.43
      C1     |18-NOV-18 12.29.43
      C2     |18-NOV-18 10.29.43
      C2     |19-NOV-18 09.29.43
      C6     |20-NOV-18 13.29.43
      C6     |21-NOV-18 14.29.43
      C1     |21-NOV-18 18.29.43
      C1     |22-NOV-18 11.29.43
```

My goal is to filter this dataframe and get new dataframe that contains tow last occurrence of each client if this occurrence is < of 24 hours for example for this example the result must be:

```
     client  |date
      C2     |18-NOV-18 10.29.43
      C2     |19-NOV-18 09.29.43
      C1     |21-NOV-18 18.29.43
      C1     |22-NOV-18 11.29.43
```

any help, please !

Comment: your question is not clear. what exactly you want as output

Comment: What is the type of `date` column?

Comment: hello @BalajiReddy I edited the question I want to get a dataframe that contains for each client the last tow observation that the deference of the date is little than 24 hours.

Comment: @anujsaxena  the date column is a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window functions. Check this out:

```
val df = Seq(("C1","08-NOV-18 11.29.43"),
  ("C2","09-NOV-18 13.29.43"),
  ("C2","09-NOV-18 18.29.43"),
  ("C3","11-NOV-18 19.29.43"),
  ("C1","12-NOV-18 10.29.43"),
  ("C2","13-NOV-18 09.29.43"),
  ("C4","14-NOV-18 20.29.43"),
  ("C1","15-NOV-18 11.29.43"),
  ("C5","16-NOV-18 15.29.43"),
  ("C10","17-NOV-18 19.29.43"),
  ("C1","18-NOV-18 12.29.43"),
  ("C2","18-NOV-18 10.29.43"),
  ("C2","19-NOV-18 09.29.43"),
  ("C6","20-NOV-18 13.29.43"),
  ("C6","21-NOV-18 14.29.43"),
  ("C1","21-NOV-18 18.29.43"),
  ("C1","22-NOV-18 11.29.43")).toDF("client","dt").withColumn("dt",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('dt,"dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")

val df2 = spark.sql(""" select * from ( select client, dt, count(*) over(partition by client ) cnt, rank() over(partition by client order by dt desc) rk1  from tbl ) t where cnt>1 and rk1 in (1,2) """)

df2.alias("t1").join(df2.alias("t2"), $"t1.client" === $"t2.client" and $"t1.rk1" =!= $"t2.rk1" , "inner" ).withColumn("dt24",(unix_timestamp($"t1.dt") - unix_timestamp($"t2.dt") )/ 3600 ).where("dt24 > -24 and dt24 < 24").select($"t1.client", $"t1.dt").show(false)
```

Results:

```
+------+-------------------+
|client|dt                 |
+------+-------------------+
|C1    |2018-11-22 11:29:43|
|C1    |2018-11-21 18:29:43|
|C2    |2018-11-19 09:29:43|
|C2    |2018-11-18 10:29:43|
+------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for this scenario:

```
  val milliSecForADay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

  val filterDatesUDF = udf { arr: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Timestamp] =>
    arr.sortWith(_ after _).toList match {
      case last :: secondLast :: _ if (last.getTime - secondLast.getTime) < milliSecForADay => Array(secondLast, last)
      case _ => Array.empty[Timestamp]
    }
  }

  val finalDF = df.groupBy("client")
    .agg(collect_list("date").as("dates"))
    .select(col("client"), explode(filterDatesUDF(col("dates"))).as("date"))
    .show()
```

In this solution, first, I am grouping the data based on the client using a `user-defined function` or `udf` for handling timestamps grouped for each client.

This is done while presuming that the `date` column already in `Timestamp` format which I think may not be true. In case you are getting the `date` column as `String` type, add the following code before the above solution to convert the type of column `date` from `String` to `Timestamp`.

```
  val stringToTimestampUDF = udf { str: String =>
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss") //format for "08-NOV-18 11.29.43"
    new Timestamp(format.parse(str).getTime)
  }

  val df = originDF.select(col("client"), to_utc_timestamp(stringToTimestampUDF(col("date")), "utc").as("date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Window function next/prev dates can be found, and then filtered rows where diff between dates bigger than 24 hours.

**Data preparation**

```
val df = Seq(("C1", "08-NOV-18 11.29.43"),
  ("C2", "09-NOV-18 13.29.43"),
  ("C2", "09-NOV-18 18.29.43"),
  ("C3", "11-NOV-18 19.29.43"),
  ("C1", "12-NOV-18 10.29.43"),
  ("C2", "13-NOV-18 09.29.43"),
  ("C4", "14-NOV-18 20.29.43"),
  ("C1", "15-NOV-18 11.29.43"),
  ("C5", "16-NOV-18 15.29.43"),
  ("C10", "17-NOV-18 19.29.43"),
  ("C1", "18-NOV-18 12.29.43"),
  ("C2", "18-NOV-18 10.29.43"),
  ("C2", "19-NOV-18 09.29.43"),
  ("C6", "20-NOV-18 13.29.43"),
  ("C6", "21-NOV-18 14.29.43"),
  ("C1", "21-NOV-18 18.29.43"),
  ("C1", "22-NOV-18 11.29.43"))
  .toDF("client", "dt")
  .withColumn("dt", to_timestamp($"dt", "dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss"))
```

**Acting code**

```
// get next/prev dates
val dateWindow = Window.partitionBy("client").orderBy("dt")
val withNextPrevDates = df
  .withColumn("previousDate", lag($"dt", 1).over(dateWindow))
  .withColumn("nextDate", lead($"dt", 1).over(dateWindow))

// function for filter
val secondsInDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)
val dateDiffLessThanDay = (startTimeStamp: Column, endTimeStamp: Column) =>
  endTimeStamp.cast(LongType) - startTimeStamp.cast(LongType) < secondsInDay && datediff(endTimeStamp, startTimeStamp) === 1

// filter
val result = withNextPrevDates
  .where(dateDiffLessThanDay($"previousDate", $"dt") || dateDiffLessThanDay($"dt", $"nextDate"))
  .drop("previousDate", "nextDate")
```

**Result**

```
+------+-------------------+
|client|dt                 |
+------+-------------------+
|C1    |2018-11-21 18:29:43|
|C1    |2018-11-22 11:29:43|
|C2    |2018-11-18 10:29:43|
|C2    |2018-11-19 09:29:43|
+------+-------------------+
```